# Why do I get these error messages in red when developing a table in Jasper Studio?

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

What do these error messages (in red FitCol, FitRow) mean when developing a table in Jasper Studio?

[image: Screen shot]

On error tab doesn't show any message.

How can I fix them?

**This is the JRXML CODE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.1.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.1.1  -->
<!-- 2016-08-25T12:40:39 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="1808" pageWidth="2800" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="2760" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isIgnorePagination="true" uuid="83010943-1966-4851-8b4c-aad3d0517ed9">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF" pattern="" isBold="true">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#17375D">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="Dataset1" uuid="b1d60b48-df80-41d7-8eaa-0cc49107e428">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="SQLSRV_SQLDEV"/>
        <parameter name="CODPEDIDO" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[90918]]></defaultValueExpression>
        </parameter>
        <queryString language="SQL">
            <![CDATA[EXEC dbo.pr_sql_server_procedure  @CodPedido =  $P{CODPEDIDO}]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="data_resp" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
        <field name="NOME_CAND" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="DTNASC_CAND" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="IDADE_CAND" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <field name="CIDADE_CAND" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="EMAIL_CAND" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="CEL_CAND" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="UltCargo_exp" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="nivel_de_formacao_academica_Desc" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="formacao_academica_Desc" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="tem_experiencia_como_docente_Desc" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="tempo_de_experiencia_profissional_Desc" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="segmento_experiencia_como_docente_Desc" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="nivel_de_experiencia_como_docente_Desc" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="estadocidade_de_atuacao_Desc" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="cursos_que_pode_ministrar_aulas_Desc" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="publicacoes__possui_Desc" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="publicacoes__quantas_Desc" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="link_para_o_curriculo_lattes" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="PATH" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["/home/diego.queres/Desenv/Relatórios Clientes/1808"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="CODPEDIDO" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[Código do pedido do relatório]]></parameterDescription>
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[90953]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString language="plsql">
        <![CDATA[SELECT 1 AS [GERAR]]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="81">
            <image scaleImage="RetainShape">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="140" height="81" uuid="b1c8d3f8-1aa1-4d3c-b23c-7933cc5bd368"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{PATH} + "/Logo.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="212" y="25" width="401" height="30" uuid="36c73e3e-05ee-4f60-b67f-7906c3054369"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[REPORT TITLE]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <summary>
        <band height="90" splitType="Prevent">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="2760" height="90" uuid="758f6154-5ad1-4973-a17d-c4aa560f766c">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="Dataset1" uuid="e746e840-22f7-455b-8c48-d328fffe6f3c">
                        <datasetParameter name="CODPEDIDO">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{CODPEDIDO}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="f113ee3f-28c0-4eca-b7c0-3576439bd602">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="60">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="60" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="3859baa0-fac3-4435-b557-ed6e8d3be9b2"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Data preenchimento da Ficha]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="6b6a4d0c-563f-4bff-ac63-4922afc9e7e4">
                                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/>
                                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column" value="true"/>
                                </reportElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{data_resp}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="99644605-94f5-4c09-a115-c478eba1a722">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="60">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="60" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="54ff5aca-26cc-4dad-ab84-46b36944e12a"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Nome]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="7026cec4-42b1-4be7-b022-cbde3a7eedb0">
                                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/>
                                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column" value="true"/>
                                </reportElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{NOME_CAND}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="0a03b7a5-b49c-4760-a6f1-b12d6bbc646d">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="60">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="60" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="8d792597-81e8-4f9a-a758-b352ba654e79"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Data Nascimento]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="e3e14b32-5893-4acb-bfe8-73bd782ae5fb">
                                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/>
                                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column" value="true"/>
                                </reportElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{DTNASC_CAND}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="6c6a4505-2ee3-436f-9071-74bcf7e42820">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="60">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="60" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="8f1d7fd5-3b7f-48b6-b967-d9be5752dbc3">
                                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/>
                                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column" value="true"/>
                                </reportElement>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Idade]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="35222a3b-fe46-47f8-8cdf-9ad0907cd68b">
                                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/>
                                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column" value="true"/>
                                </reportElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{IDADE_CAND}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="b85a3099-2c1f-4b57-bc98-00d53780e25a">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="60">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="60" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="991f79a0-31d5-47a3-b943-760cd4e0d186"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Cidade]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="4db67ac3-270a-4ad5-aaa9-d460ffc1c332">
                                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/>
                                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column" value="true"/>
                                </reportElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CIDADE_CAND}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="4207331a-d3d5-454d-ae58-e84f442c9c4a">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="60">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="60" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="0b4792b6-b364-41f9-a889-55f97da64324"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[E-mail]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="c1f57528-8425-491e-b9b6-b0354d80de9f">
                                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/>
                                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column" value="true"/>
                                </reportElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{EMAIL_CAND}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="7a32b248-2fe0-41ec-aa4a-767119c61f7e">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="60">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="60" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="3a1e253b-a860-4568-86a8-7077c1533a65"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Telefone Celular]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="4251eda8-07c2-44c5-a9f6-dc6d3b84b0c6">
                                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/>
                                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column" value="true"/>
                                </reportElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CEL_CAND}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="039b7e62-a65e-425c-aeb8-b37f91a9749f">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="60">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="60" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="fb57b137-a5a4-4d47-be6c-f59af977a34f"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Cargo Atual]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="6409aebd-adab-49a7-a936-1106b2698552">
                                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/>
                                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column" value="true"/>
                                </reportElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{UltCargo_exp}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="400af683-0f3e-466d-81fd-5728fb9ea2d7">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="60">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="60" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="6b10bc3f-6b2d-45b0-8eb6-2c0213d39bea"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Nível formação acadêmica]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="fd0f8ebd-a8cc-4630-bbf1-75aaee74b355">
                                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/>
                                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column" value="true"/>
                                </reportElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{nivel_de_formacao_academica_Desc}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="f6fb8c6f-7d30-491c-a858-90d1ec0c9263">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="60">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="60" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="459f1592-4eba-4cbb-a568-749a7f07ac71"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Formação Acadêmica]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="10057bf6-7836-4f63-9783-b3463f0cf3d9">
                                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/>
                                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column" value="true"/>
                                </reportElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{formacao_academica_Desc}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="c9bdfa6b-ac9d-482c-a1bd-552fc9b0f5c2">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="60">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="60" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="6a11a4a8-2163-4e60-a912-035e51d1511b"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Possui experiência como Docente?]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="d53a8990-e900-4d65-884b-4744129ea42a">
                                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/>
                                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column" value="true"/>
                                </reportElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{tem_experiencia_como_docente_Desc}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

This error is only inside Jasper Studio. When i generate report inside application doens't occur errors.

I'm using JasperSoft Studio Community Edition 6.1.1

Comment: Ok. I'm using JasperSoft Studio Community Edition 6.1.1

Answer (score 1):

Those indicate 2 **excel properties**, hence they have effect only if you export to excel and are **not error messages**

**FitRow** `net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row=true`

> Flag property that indicates whether Excel should autofit the current row height.

**FitCol**  `net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column=true`

> Flag property that indicates whether Excel should autofit the current column width.

You can change these by either editing the jrxml (set true or false, or remove property) or in JasperSoft Studio: select textField, `Properties >> Appearance >> Edit Properties`